# VPN not working?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pptp

For some reason when I startup a VPN with PPTP or OpenVPN, it won't let me run Minecraft. On Chrome, it does work. On Minecraft, it just kept the connecting to the server screen up. Could this possibly have to do with the fact that it shows my ipv6 address as my public ip instead of my ipv4? I checked a website that shows me my ipv4 address and it changed, but my ipv6 address stayed the same when I ran the VPN.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that I have tried many PPTP connections and a few OpenVPN.

Comment: I just changed to ipv4 and same thing happens.

Comment: Since nobody answered, I'm going to assume that it's my firewall